# Showing that $c_n=\cos\frac\pi{2^n}$ satisfies the recurrence $c_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1+c_n}2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, proof-writing, solution-verification

> From the identity $\cos(\alpha) = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2\alpha)}{2}}$ with $0 \leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, show that the sequence $c_n = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$ satisfies the recurrence relation $$c_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1+c_n}{2}}$$

What I did was:

Say that $\alpha_n = \frac{\pi}{2^n}$. We first must prove $0 \leq \alpha_n \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. By induction:

Base case is trivial: $0 \leq \frac{\pi}{2^1} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

For $p(n) \Rightarrow p(n+1)$:
$0 \leq \frac{\pi}{2^n} \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \iff 0 \leq \frac{\pi}{2^n}\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2} \iff 0 \leq \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} \leq \frac{\pi}{4} < \frac{\pi}{2}$

So it is true that $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1} \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and we can write $c_n = \cos(a_n)$.

Therefore:

$$c_1 = \cos(\alpha_1) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$$

$$c_n = \cos(\alpha) \iff 1+c_n = 1+\cos(\alpha)\iff \frac{1+c_n}{2} = \frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}$$
$$\iff \sqrt{\frac{1+c_n}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}}$$

But $\sqrt{\frac{1+c_n}{2}}$ would be the following term for $c_n$, meaning $c_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{1+c_n}{2}}$.

This was my atempt to prove it but I can't tell if it actually proves the recurrence. How could I prove recurrence relations in sequences like this?

Comment: No proof by induction is needed. It's just straightforward from the trigonometric formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing much more work than you have to. As @Surb notes, you just need to verify $\cos\tfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}=\sqrt{\tfrac{1+\cos\tfrac{\pi}{2^n}}{2}}$, which is the case $\alpha=\tfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$

$c_{n+1} = \cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} = \cos\alpha$ and $c_n = \cos\frac{\pi}{2^n} =  \cos\frac{2\pi}{2^{n+1}} = \cos(2\alpha)$

Now, $\cos(\alpha) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos(2\alpha)}{2}} \Rightarrow c_{n+1} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+c_n}{2}}$

Comment: I'm not so sure in what this answer is helpful...

Comment: @Surb The OP already has the formula that relates $\cos \alpha $ and $\cos 2\alpha$. So I just added to take $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$